# Spark Streaming Job Keeps growing memory

Tags: apache-spark, memory-leaks, spark-streaming

I am running spark v 1.6.1 on a single machine in standalone mode, having 64GB RAM and 16cores.

I have created five worker instances to create five executor as in standalone mode, there cannot be more than one executor in one worker node.

### Configuration:

> SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES    5
>
> SPARK_WORKER_CORE   1
>
> SPARK_MASTER_OPTS "-Dspark.deploy.default.Cores=5"

all other configurations are default in `spark_env.sh`

I am running a spark streaming direct kafka job at an interval of 1 min, which takes data from kafka and after some aggregation write the data to mongo.

### Problems:

> when I start master and slave, it starts one master process and five worker processes. each only consume about 212 MB of ram.when i submit the job , it again creates 5 executor processes and 1 job process and also the memory uses grows to 8GB in total and keeps growing over time (slowly) also when there is no data to process.

we are unpersisting cached rdd at the end also set `spark.cleaner.ttl` to 600. but still memory is growing.

> one more thing, I have seen the merged SPARK-1706, then also why i am unable to create multiple executor within a worker.and also in `spark_env.sh` file , setting any configuration related to executor comes under YARN only mode.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you figure this out?